# What keyboard shortcut open a smart tag menu in Word/Outlook?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-word-2010

A lot of times in Office you get a small blue rectangle under some text, usually with the options for auto corrections (see screenshot below for an example). How can I access this menu using my keyboard?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortcut is ***Shift + Alt + F10*** and is context aware.

Comment: Great, works in Word 2010 but not in Outlook messages unfortunately.